# javascript move using div width

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following code and it seems like the .style does not recognize my variable wid! what is wrong with it?

```
var wid = document.getElementById("bd").offsetWidth/2;
obj = document.getElementById('div1'); 
obj.style.left = wid.toString();
```

'bd' is the id of my body and 'div1' the id of the div i want to move.
If I just use the following, it works fine:

```
obj.style.left = '10px';
```

Comment: Why are you giving the body element a name? For the width of your body you can use this: var wid = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].clientWidth;

Comment: `console.log()` or `alert()` your variable `wid`. What does it give you? Also, when you do `wid.toString()` what is that giving you? Do you have `px` on the end of that?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference... I did it anyway though

Comment: I did not put px although I tried to alert the var and I got the correct values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok... I just changed my code from:

```
obj.style.left = wid.toString();
```

to:

```
object.style.left = wid.toString()+'px';
```

and it worked fine

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `toString`, just append **`px`** to the number :

```
var wid = document.getElementById("bd").offsetWidth/2;
obj = document.getElementById('div1'); 
obj.style.left = wid + 'px';
```